# Keeping track of changes using rails - "changed?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am building a multi lingual website, using ruby on rails, where part of the content is supposed to be user generated and they are supposed to be able to create different versions of it for all languages. The language support is handled by i18n gem.

Part of their content is created using Markdown through http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics .

In my database I save: object.content_markdown_en, object.content_html_en, object.content_markdown_sv, object.content_html_sv and so on for the different locales.

Now if a user changes the content, new html is supposed to be generated. But it seems unnecessary to regenerate the html for all locales if he only made changes in one of the languages.

I thought there might be some way to use something like

```
if object.content_markdown_[locale]_changed?
  generate_new_html
end
```

that can be run in a loop for all possible locales. But I can't find any nice ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
[:en, :sv].each do |locale|
    if object.send("content_markdown_#{ locale }_changed?".to_sym)
        send("generate_new_#{ locale }_html".to_sym)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) to call methods by name:

```
object.send("content_markdown_#{locale}_changed?".to_sym)
```

Your loop would look like this:

```
%w(en sv).each { |locale|
  if object.send("content_markdown_#{locale}_changed?".to_sym)
    generate_new_html
  end
}
```

However, using a separate translation table might be a better approach.

Comment: Also, you started the block with `{`, but closed it with `end`